# Magento How to redirect to homepage after register

Tags: magento, redirect

I'm creating an ecommerce website using magento. Currently if a new user registers the url is redirecting to my account page. I want to show homepage once a new user registers my site.

Guide me to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please see my answer for an upgrade friendly approach. The currently accepted answer does not follow Magento development practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the **Account Controller** and add the code **$successUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl();** before the line **return $successUrl;** in the function **_welcomeCustomer()**

Comment: No, do NOT do this. Class files within app/code/core should not be directly modified. It does not follow upgrade friendly development practices and if you were to upgrade Magento after having done so your modifications will be lost.

Comment: Please see my answer for an upgrade friendly approach.

Answer (score 4):

While this is an old post I feel urged to offer a new answer here as many of the other answers blatantly do not follow Magento best practices (ex: modifying core files directly) or (while it works) they unnecessarily rewrite the Customer Account Controller.

The solution below is performed entirely through the use of an observer class instead. Doing so in this way will ensure your logic is not lost by upgrading Magento (if you had directly modified core class files), also should Magento's core development team ever choose to tweak the `Mage_Customer_AccountController::createPostAction` method those changes will be brought in when you upgrade your site (which wouldn't had you rewritten the controller class file).

In the steps below, create any directories as necessary to create the files mentioned.

**Step 1: Define your module**

app/etc/modules/Stackoverflow_Question10470629.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Stackoverflow_Question10470629>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Stackoverflow_Question10470629>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Step 2: Define your module configuration**

app/code/local/Stackoverflow/Question10470629/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Stackoverflow_Question10470629>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Stackoverflow_Question10470629>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <stackoverflow_question10470629>
                <class>Stackoverflow_Question10470629_Model</class>
            </stackoverflow_question10470629>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_createPost>
                <observers>
                    <stackoverflow_question10470629>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>stackoverflow_question10470629/observer_frontend</class>
                        <method>controllerActionPostdispatchCreatePostAction</method>
                    </stackoverflow_question10470629>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_createPost>
            <customer_register_success>
                <observers>
                    <stackoverflow_question10470629>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>stackoverflow_question10470629/observer_frontend</class>
                        <method>customerRegisterSuccess</method>
                    </stackoverflow_question10470629>
                </observers>
            </customer_register_success>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**Step 3: Define your observer class**

app/code/local/Stackoverflow/Question10470629/Model/Observer/Frontend.php

```
<?php
/**
 * All publicly accessible method names correspond to the event they observe.
 *
 * @category    Stackoverflow
 * @package     Stackoverflow_Question10470629
 */
class Stackoverflow_Question10470629_Model_Observer_Frontend
{

    /**
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function customerRegisterSuccess($observer)
    {
        /* @var $session Mage_Customer_Model_Session */
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

        // This event occurs within Mage_Customer_AccountController::createPostAction
        // however it occurs before the controller sets it's own redirect settings.
        // Therefore we set this flag to true now, and then within the postdispatch
        // we'll redirect to our custom URL
        $session->setData('customer_register_success', true);
    }

    /**
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function controllerActionPostdispatchCreatePostAction($observer)
    {
        /* @var $controller Mage_Customer_AccountController */
        /* @var $session Mage_Customer_Model_Session */

        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

        // We must test for a successful customer registration because they
        // could have failed registration despite reaching postdispatch
        // (for example: they used an existing email address)
        if ($session->getData('customer_register_success')) {
            $session->unsetData('customer_register_success');

            $url        = Mage::getBaseUrl();    
            $controller = $observer->getData('controller_action');
            $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Redirection after logged In, Logged Out and Registration is very common issue in magento. Please find the code below, it can help you.

```
public function customerRegistration(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)    
{    
    $_session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');      
    $_session->setBeforeAuthUrl(CustomUrl);    
}
```

Customurl is a url on which you want to redirect after registraion.

If you want complete solution for custom url redirection for your ecommerce website after logged In, Logged Out and Registration. Custom Redirection extension can help you. Click on link to get extension. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-redirection.html

Comment: I like the extension. Would much rather use it than monkeying with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if the Backend rettings for redirecting users after login is what you need.
Go to System> Configurarion > under Clients tab - Clients configuration > Login Options > select No

The default functionality is to redirect the user to the last/current page he visited before login. In my opinion this should be useful if you what the customer to finalize the transaction of the product who make him to act and log-in.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code in customer account controller

Find function _successProcessRegistration and

Replace `$url = $this->_welcomeCustomer($customer); // line 350`

With `$url = Mage::getBaseUrl();`

Answer (score -1):

You can override the AccountController in order to redirect the customer to the page where you want.
If you need a ready made solution which works great then you can try the following Extension:
http://www.magepsycho.com/custom-login-redirect-pro.html

Comment: It is unnecessary to override the AccountController for this situation. The solution can be done entirely through an observer class. Please see my answer for an example.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your customer AccountController:

```
aap->core->code->Mage->customer->controllers->AccountController.php
```

Then search for `_welcomeCustomer()` function

replace this code :

```
$successUrl = $this->_getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure' => true));
```

With : `$successUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl();`

This `$successUrl` will return user to home page after registration.

Comment: This approach is NOT an upgrade-friendly approach and the modifications to the account controller will be lost if Magento is ever upgraded. Please see my answer for an approach which utilizes an observer class instead.