# Magento: How to redirect a logged in user to the home page

Tags: magento, redirect, authentication

I'm using Magento 1.7 and I would like to redirect all my clients after login to the home page.

I'm using the [extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/wabism-members-only-7590.html) to close the site to non logged in users. I'm not using the default login page, but a CMS page with a facebook connect button.

Right now, after the user logs in with facebook, magento is loading the same page without the facebook connect button.

I have seen this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470629/magento-how-to-redirect-to-homepage-after-register), but did not find the AccountManager to modify it. Where is it? Also, I'm not sure that this would work, since the redirection in my case is not happening to the customer's dashboard, but to the cms page I created.

How (and where in the code) can I check if a user is logged in and redirect him/her to the home page?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

One approach would be to hook onto the `**customer_login**` event and set the afterAuthUrl in the customer session.

```
...
public function customerLogin(Varient_Event_Observer $observer) {
    /* @var $session Mage_Customer_Model_Session */
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    $session->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl());
}
```

You can view Magento's logic in the `AccountController` `_loginPostRedirect` method `(app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php)`. Based on the implementation you'll notice it is also possible to send a referrer request parameter (note: it must be `base64` encoded via `Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode())`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is an extension made by AITOC that does what you are trying to do. In case you're interested in purchasing rather than building.

Answer (score 0):

using event  as mentioned by @beep logic with method from customer session `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl($url);` helped in redirection to desired page.
Hope this helps